# How can I learn botany/plant ID by myself?

Tags: botany, microbiology, ecology, taxonomy

I am interested in sources and methods regarding botany and plant ID, and being a self-taught person. Textbooks, sites etc.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Thank you for taking the [tour], but please carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [ask] a good question. In particular, questions that are inherently opinion based are not appropriate for this site. You can try asking for advice in the [chat], but please delete this post. Thanks!

Comment: Your local public library should have books, including field guides to local plants.  For a more general view, there are lots of on-line resources, for instance a couple of OpenStax texts on biology: https://openstax.org/subjects/science

Comment: Thank you for the useful answers!

Comment: Really, start with identifying the most common plants in your area, especially weeds. try to learn family as well as genus and species - then you will see similarities within families. When I was a horticulture student I learnt ten plants each week.